# nhibernate one-to-many collection- retrieve only the superclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following classes:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

class Company
{
    public IList<Person> PeopleWhoAreNotEmployees { get; set; }
}
```

Person and Employee are mapped using table-per-class-heirarchy strategy.

When I retrieve the PeopleWhoAreNotEmployees collection, I want it only to contain elements that are Person, and NOT Employees.
How can I (fluently) configure the collection to only retrieve elements of the super class?
I think it's something to do with the Polymorphism property, but I couldn't really figure out how to do that.

thanks,
Jhonny

EDIT:
following the discussion with Jamie, I feel I need to clarify that the case here isn't really Person and Employee, but more like Employee and HistoricalEmployee.
Meaning- when an employee 'dies', they're not really deleted,
 but they become HistoricalEmployee (with a few more attributes, such as termination date etc.).
Obviously, over time, the number of HistoricalEmployees will exceed the number of Employees by magnitudes,
 so I can't fetch all HistoricalEmployees when I only need current Employees.
Sorry for the ambigiuity of the original question...
J

P.S.
 I didn't change the original question since it would make the answer irrelevant.
 a new version of this question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540936/nhibernate-a-collection-which-would-contain-only-a-supertype/4540965#4540965)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I ended up doing was using a 'where' clause on my property.
the fluent configuration looks like so:

```
 mapping.HasMany(x => x.Employees)
            .Where("IsFired = 0")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, but that's not how I would approach it anyway. I would use a private field for the collection and expose methods that filter the list. This is much easier to map and work with and performance will be fine if the collection is reasonably sized (I don't know what's reasonable but I wouldn't worry about it if it's < 1000). It would make it easier if you had an abstract PersonBase class that both Person and Employee extend so that you don't have to deal with uncertainty that a Person might be an Employee.

```
public class Company
{
    private IList<Person> _allPeople;

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees()
    {
        return _allPeople.OfType<Employee>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> PeopleWhoAreNotEmployees()
    {
        return _allPeople.Where(x => !(x is Employee));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In response to your comment, the filtering would take place in the class. The private collection would cause all the People to be loaded, and the properties would dynamically filter that collection. The mapping wold look like:

```
public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap ()
    {
        // only collection is shown w/o cascade option
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Person).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that looks very reasonable.couple of questions: 1. (nHiberntae nub question) how would my mapping look like for this? will I map the private field? 2. does the .Where(..) guartantees that the filtering will occur at the DB level or will all the existing People objects will be loaded, and then filtered at application-level?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jamie. Unfortunately this solution isn't acceptable for me, since in my case, there are MUCH more Employees than Persons, so I can't afford to load all employees to app-level and filter them there; Is there any way to make sure the filtering occurs at DB level?

Comment: Have you profiled the performance? What's the typical number of records loaded? Is it normal to access the PeopleWhoAreNotEmployees collection without accessing the Employees collection in the same session?

Comment: I haven't profiled it, but I think I may have given a bad example; I perhaps over-simplified it. I've edited the original question to (hopefully) make the case a bit clearer.

Comment: @sJohnny. That makes more sense. I thing you should ask a new question with the clarifications to get a better variety of answers. Off the top of my head, I would consider not exposing the inheritance to NHibernate but leaving it in the domain model (or using an interface). HistoricalEmployee would still extend Employee but NHibernate would not know about the relationship.

Comment: quite right. here's the new question, and I've already answered it.. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540936/nhibernate-a-collection-which-would-contain-only-a-supertype/4540965#4540965